# Reduced latin square that does not fit quadrangle criterion

Tags: graph-theory, latin-square

I have been having trouble figuring out exactly visually when a certain reduced Latin square does not fit the quadrangle criterion; especially when you can flip things to match. So this is my attempt at finding bits in a square that doesn't fit it. Can I get a confirmation that I am doing it right or not

For an order 5
\begin{bmatrix}
    0       & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
    1      & 0 & 3 & 4 & 2 \\
    2       & 3 & 4 & 0& 1 \\
    3      & 4 & 1 & 2 & 0 \\
    4       & 2 & 0 & 1 & 3 \\
\end{bmatrix}

Counter examples of the criterion

\begin{bmatrix}
    0       & 1 \\
    1      & 0  
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    0       & 1 \\
    2      & 0  
\end{bmatrix}

and
\begin{bmatrix}
    1       &0 \\
    2      & 3  
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    4       & 2 \\
    0      & 1  
\end{bmatrix}

Examples that do fit it

\begin{bmatrix}
    3       &4 \\
    4      & 2  
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    3       & 4 \\
    4      & 2  
\end{bmatrix}

and not in the square but something like this would satisfy the criterion right, by a flip and reflect.
\begin{bmatrix}
    1       &2 \\
    2      & 4  
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    4       & 2 \\
    2      & 1  
\end{bmatrix}

I think I have also seen examples where people take 1 by 2 sub matrixes and combine it with another 1 by 2 in the same square and do that again to either find a counter or example like:

\begin{bmatrix}
    0       &2 \\
    1      & 3  
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    1       & 1 \\
    0      & 2  
\end{bmatrix}

in this case with the sub matrixes taken from the order 5 square it does not fit the criterion

Comment: You might want to give a bit more context to your question. What is a Latin square? What is the quadrangle criterion?